# Visual Studio Code run venv python

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda, vscode-debugger, python-venv

I created a venv in python. In CMD I can execute it with

```
Python\pyenv\Scripts\activate
```

and run my Scripts after that

```
python example.py
```

But how do I do it automatically in Visual Studio Code? If I press F5 or CTRL+F5 VSC tries to run another Python version but not my venv. In `settings.json` I have path to my venv:

```
{
"python.pythonPath": "Python\\pyver\\py391\\python.exe"
}
```

I need to write somewhere in my setting the `Python\pyenv\Scripts\activate` and execute it with `python`  like Anaconda is doing it. I can see in my terminal if I press F5 with Anaconda it runs first`path\to\Scripts\activate` and after that it activade `conda base` and runs the python script. How do I set my setting like in Anaconda?

Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to select the interpreter: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments

Comment: @Steinfeld. Also there's a default setting `"python.terminal.activateEnvironment": true,` which can activate the environment automatically when you open a new Terminal(Ctrl+Shift+`). So you don't have to activate it manually every time in the Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

The `python.pythonPath` in your `settings.json` should be either absolute filepath or be prepended with [`${workspaceFolder}`](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/variables-reference):

```
"python.pythonPath": "${workspaceFolder}/Python/pyver/py391/python.exe"
```

The `${workspaceFolder}` will be replaced with the path of the folder opened in VS Code.